# cannot serialize a bytes object larger than 4 GiB in deep learning

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I am working on Google **Colab** environment to create a **Siamese** network using Keras to verify the images. I have used [this](https://github.com/akshaysharma096/Siamese-Networks) code from GitHub. But I get an error when I tried to run the `pickle.dump` code:

```
with open(os.path.join(save_path,"train.pickle"), "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump((X,c),f)
```

The error message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-af9d0618d385> in <module>()
      3 
      4 with open(os.path.join(save_path,"train.pickle"), "wb") as f:
----> 5         pickle.dump((X,c),f)
      6 
      7 

OverflowError: cannot serialize a bytes object larger than 4 GiB
```

**I found some related questions in this website, but I could not find a useful answer.** How can I solve this error?

Comment: Please add a question, you have a problem but I am not sure what kind of solution you are expecting.

Answer (score 9):

Use pickle with `protocol=4`, e.g.,

```
pickle.dump((X,c), f, protocol=4)
```

Comment: I tried this code several times, but the session stopped during running this code and I got this message "Session crash for an unknown reason "